# Design Issue: Trying to avoid code duplication using scala type bounds

Tags: scala, design-patterns, code-duplication

I'm new to Scala, and I'm trying to use type bounds to avoid code duplication in the following code (cleaned from irrelevant stuff):

```
trait StandardStep1[-I1] {
  def next_step(i:I1):StandardStep2
}

trait StandardStep2

trait UniqueStep1[-I1] extends StandardStep1[I1] {
  def next_step(i:I1):UniqueStep2
}

trait UniqueStep2 extends StandardStep2

class DoubleStandardStep1[-IL,-IR](left:StandardStep1[IL], right:StandardStep1[IR]) extends StandardStep1[(IL,IR)] {
  def next_step(i:(IL,IR)) = {
    val (i_left, i_right) = i
    val new_left = left.next_step(i_left)
    val new_right = right.next_step(i_right)
    new DoubleStandardStep2(new_left, new_right)
  }
}

class DoubleStandardStep2(left:StandardStep2, right:StandardStep2) extends StandardStep2

class DoubleUniqueStep1[-IL,-IR](left:UniqueStep1[IL], right:UniqueStep1[IR]) extends UniqueStep1[(IL,IR)] {
  def next_step(i:(IL,IR)) = {
    val (i_left, i_right) = i
    val new_left = left.next_step(i_left)
    val new_right = right.next_step(i_right)
    new DoubleUniqueStep2(new_left, new_right)
  }
}

class DoubleUniqueStep2(left:UniqueStep2, right:UniqueStep2) extends UniqueStep2
```

Explanation:

`StandardStep1` represents a step in some state machine, and has a `next_step` operation that gives a `StandardStep2` for a given input.

`UniqueStep1` is a special type of `StandardStep1` which gives a `UniqueStep2` when it's `next_step` is called - and obviously `UniqueStep2` has to inherit from `StandardStep2` for that.

Now I had to write a *DoubleStep* wrappers: `DoubleStandardStep1` wraps too `StandardStep1`s, and returns a `DoubleStandardStep2` when its `next_step` is called.
`DoubleUniqueStep1` does the same thing, but it returns a `DoubleUniqueStep2`.

The implementation of the *DoubleStep*s' `next_step` has an obvious code duplication: they both split the input into `i_left` and `i_right` and call their wrapped steps' `next_step` in the same way.

I wondered how to eliminate this code duplication, by creating a generic abstract *DoubleStep1* that will do this part of the code:

```
object DoubleStepHelper {
  def next_step_args[IL,IR,SL <: StandardStep1[IL],SR <: StandardStep1[IR]](left:SL,right:SR)(i:(IL,IR)) = { 
    val (i_left, i_right) = i
    val new_left = left.next_step(i_left)
    val new_right = right.next_step(i_right)
    (new_left, new_right)
  }
}

class DoubleStandardStep1[-IL,-IR](left:StandardStep1[IL], right:StandardStep1[IR]) extends StandardStep1[(IL,IR)] {
  def next_step(i:(IL,IR)) = {
    ((l,r) => new DoubleStandardStep2(l,r)).tupled(DoubleStepHelper.next_step_args(left,right)(i))
  }
}

class DoubleStandardStep2(left:StandardStep2, right:StandardStep2) extends StandardStep2


class DoubleUniqueStep1[-IL,-IR](left:UniqueStep1[IL], right:UniqueStep1[IR]) extends UniqueStep1[(IL,IR)] {
  def next_step(i:(IL,IR)) = {
    ((l,r) => new DoubleUniqueStep2(l,r)).tupled(DoubleStepHelper.next_step_args(left,right)(i))
  }
}

class DoubleUniqueStep2(left:UniqueStep2, right:UniqueStep2) extends UniqueStep2
```

Trying to compile this code (scala 2.9.2) fails with the message:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (this.StandardStep2, this.StandardStep2)
 required: (this.UniqueStep2, this.UniqueStep2)
    ((l,r) => new DoubleUniqueStep2(l,r)).tupled(DoubleStepHelper.next_step_args(left,right)(i))
                                                                                            ^
```

I assume this happens because `DoubleStepHelper.next_step_args` is assumed to return a `(StandardStep2, StandardStep2)` value, which is bad when we want wrap it with **`DoubleUniqueStep2`**.

Can you think of a way to solve this issue? How to tell the compiler that `DoubleStepHelper`'s next_step_args may return a `(UniqueStep2, UniqueStep2)` if `SL` and `SR` inherit from `UniqueStep1`?

A nice feature could be to be able to define the result type of `next_step_args` to something like *(SL.next_step, SR.next_step)*, meaning that its return type is built from the return types of specific functions (*next_step*) in `SL` and `SR`.

Could "view" bounds solve it in any way?

I could force casting using *asInstanceOf*, but this looks ugly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution. I created `AbstractStep1` and `AbstractDoubleStep1` in which the type of the following step is given as as a type parameter.

Then I can inherit from this class with the cases where the next-step is `StandardStep2` or `UniqueStep2`.

So here's the code:

```
trait AbstractStep1[-I,+S2] {
  def next_step(i:I):S2
}

trait StandardStep1[-I] extends AbstractStep1[I,StandardStep2]

trait StandardStep2

trait UniqueStep1[-I] extends AbstractStep1[I,UniqueStep2] with StandardStep1[I]

trait UniqueStep2 extends StandardStep2

abstract class AbstractDoubleStep1[-IL,-IR,-S2L <: StandardStep2,-S2R <: StandardStep2,+S2](left:AbstractStep1[IL,S2L],right:AbstractStep1[IR,S2R]) extends AbstractStep1[(IL,IR),S2] {
  def wrapper(l:S2L,r:S2R):S2

  def next_step(i:(IL,IR)):S2 = {
    val (i_left, i_right) = i
    val new_left = left.next_step(i_left)
    val new_right = right.next_step(i_right)
    wrapper(new_left, new_right)
  }
}

class DoubleStandardStep1[-IL,-IR](left:StandardStep1[IL], right:StandardStep1[IR]) extends AbstractDoubleStep1[IL,IR,StandardStep2,StandardStep2,DoubleStandardStep2](left,right) {
  def wrapper(l:StandardStep2,r:StandardStep2) = {
    new DoubleStandardStep2(l,r)
  }
}

class DoubleStandardStep2(left:StandardStep2, right:StandardStep2) extends StandardStep2


class DoubleUniqueStep1[-IL,-IR](left:UniqueStep1[IL], right:UniqueStep1[IR]) extends AbstractDoubleStep1[IL,IR,UniqueStep2,UniqueStep2,DoubleUniqueStep2](left,right) {
  def wrapper(l:UniqueStep2,r:UniqueStep2) = {
    new DoubleUniqueStep2(l,r)
  }
}

class DoubleUniqueStep2(left:UniqueStep2, right:UniqueStep2) extends UniqueStep2
```

I think it is also possible to convert `AbstractDoubleStep1` to a *triat* instead of an *abstract class*, which will make it more useful in mixin inheritence, but this is not important to me at the moment.